# Local patches repository while switching kernels

Tags: git, linux-kernel

I’m new to git, 
My scenario is as follows:
I have patches made to a linux kernel on a private project. 
I want my local repository to hold these patches. Not the entire kernel. 
I ain’t talking about .patch files but rather hold the files i’m actually changing.

So that when i want to apply them on a different kernel i’ll simply pull them into the second kernel folder.

And now for the problem:
I need to be able to switch the base tree once in a while, or, to simplify the scenario, i want to be able to pull a different tree and the pull my patches-repo into it.

But the actual second kernel is a repo, and my patches are a repo as well. 
So i cannot combine them both in the same folder while still having source control for both.

Is there a way to glue the repos or tell git one is the parent and one is the child and it will auto-merge and pull everything automatically ?

Regards
David

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to glue the repos or tell git one is the parent and one is the child and it will auto-merge and pull everything automatically ?

This is basically the purpose of `git submodule` but they won't auto-*merge*. A submodule has to be at least in a given subdirectory in the main repo.

However, if your Linux hack is not about patching existing official files, but writing a distinct kernel *module* that could be loaded with *insmod* or *modprobe*, then you don't need at all to develop inside the kernel tree. Just designate a regular directory somewhere in which you'll do all your development, then ask the top-level linux makefile to compile it for you from here :

```
make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=`pwd` modules
```

Comment: Thanks. I’m patching official files.  This is a research project